# chromatic number for $k$-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a connected graph that is $k$-regular and is neither a complete graph nor an odd cycle. Then the chromatic number of $G$ is $k$. Is it true?

Comment: Not quite. [Brooks’ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) says that in that case the chromatic number of $G$ is *at most* $k$, but it can be less, as it is, for instance, when $G=K_{k,k}$ and $k>2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. For instance, the utility graph $K_{3,3}$ is cubic, i.e. 3-regular. However, it is also bipartite. It is well-known that a graph is 2-colorable if and only if it is bipartite. So we have a counterexample.